# How can I limit text to 300 characters and show again all characters?

Tags: jquery, substring

I limit my text to 300 characters. But I am not able to remove the limitation by click on "read more"

```js
$(".elipsis").text(function () {
     return $(this).text().substring(0, 300) + '...';
});
    
    
$( ".more" ).click(function() {
$(this).siblings('.content').children('.elipsis').text();
    ($(this).text() === "READ MORE") ? $(this).text("- READ LESS") : $(this).text("READ MORE");
 });
```

```css
.more{
cursor:pointer;
color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="content"><div class="elipsis">At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat</div></div>
<a class="more">READ MORE</a>


<div class="content"><div class="elipsis">At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat</div></div>
<a class="more">READ MORE</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Inside your event handler you aren't actually changing any of the text value inside the div's with the `.elipses` class.
2. You need to store the original full length text in a variable that is accessible inside your on click event callback,

   or

   I recommend you have two div's inside the parent `.content` div's, each inner div will have either the full length text or the 300 char length text, then when the click event fires all you need to do is toggle the `display` attribute between the short or full length version.

You can make it work with the current markup structure but you need to store the full length text somewhere in the script and toggle between that and the substring version when the click event is fired.

3. one more note, currently you are matching multiple elements inside your jquery function calls when you are accessing them by class. You need to find a way to get more specific and grab a single one, the one the user is interacting with to be precise, you can achieve that by assigning id's to your div's or by nesting your anchor tags inside the outer `.content` divs or by using the the call to jquery's `prev()`

Comment: Thank you,  that is actually not a bad idea! I am just wondering why it is not possible to make a substring to a text and then just remove it

Answer (score 1):

You can overflow text by appending ellipsis to it with css.
Here is a solution combining the css given at https://codepen.io/martinwolf/pen/qlFdp with some jquery:

```js
$(".more").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var $this = $(this);
  var isMore = ($(this).text() === "READ MORE");
  if (isMore) {
    $this.prev().find(".elipsis").css({
      height: "auto",
      display: "block"
    });

    $this.text("- READ LESS");
  } else {
    $this.prev().find(".elipsis").css({
      height: "56px",
      display: "-webkit-box"
    });

    $this.text("READ MORE");
  }

});
```

```css
.more {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: blue;
}

.elipsis {
  display: block;
  display: -webkit-box;
  height: 56px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="content">
  <div class="elipsis">At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia
    animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda
    est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis
    voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat</div>
</div>
<a class="more">READ MORE</a>


<div class="content">
  <div class="elipsis">At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia
    animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda
    est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis
    voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat</div>
</div>
<a class="more">READ MORE</a>
```

Here is the animated version:

```js
$(".more").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var $this = $(this);
  var isMore = ($(this).text() === "READ MORE");
  var $elipsis = $this.prev().find(".elipsis");

  if (isMore) {
    $elipsis.css({
      height: $elipsis.get(0).scrollHeight,
      display: "block"
    });

    $this.text("- READ LESS");
  } else {
    $elipsis.css({
      height: "56px",
      display: "-webkit-box"
    });

    $this.text("READ MORE");
  }

});
```

```css
.more {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: blue;
}

.elipsis {
  display: block;
  display: -webkit-box;
  height: 56px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  transition: height 500ms ease-in-out; /* this line animates the height property */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="elipsis">At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia
    animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda
    est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis
    voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat</div>
</div>
<a class="more">READ MORE</a>


<div class="content">
  <div class="elipsis">At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia
    animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda
    est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis
    voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat</div>
</div>
<a class="more">READ MORE</a>
```

Comment: thank you. this is a good idea. But I need a specific amount of characters

Comment: Is it possible to slide open this variation?

Comment: @Jarla edited the previous one and added sliding animation. Please see the comment in fiddle's css.

Comment: That is awesome! Just one last question. I put in my question at the end of the text three points"..." I still didn't figure out how to do this with your solution. I am testing it and let you know as soon as I got it

Comment: @Jarla I think I didn't get your problem clearly. Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: Your text is for examle:

Comment: At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti

Comment: What I need is this:

Comment: At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti...

Comment: See this:  `...` (it is important so that the user sees that there is more text coming)

Comment: You can see it in my question when you click on RUN CODE SNIPPET

Comment: @Jarla Please check it on chrome. It is already displaying ellipses (...) at the end.

Comment: Yes, you are right! It is actually not working in Firefox. Do you know why?

Comment: I found also another issue. Just to let you know. The animated version is not working in safari